# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04.6

Tags: 14.04

When I am running update-manager from terminal getting below error.
If manually checking updater it is saying System is up to date

```
(update-manager:4854): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(update-manager:4854): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

Comment: I would have preferred it if you had included far more output than those messages. Also I  have to assume you are using desktop as you haven't said, but it's better if we aren't guessing.  Have you tried `do-release-upgrade` ?  (but I would `sudo apt-get update` and check for any errors/issues or unusual sources being used  (possibly remove or purge), then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ensuring there are no issues first)

Comment: when i use sudo apt-get update no error comes.    then sudo apt-get dist-upgrade gives 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.    and lastly   for  do-release-upgrade command I got   sam@Sam:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: `grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` please.

Comment: This glibc is posted all over the net, seen on standard 14.04 to 16.04 update, and no solutions to be found.